# Почему-то не работает RewriteRule в .htaccess

Tags: php, веб-программирование, .htaccess

Не могу понять почему не работает `RewriteRule`, `RewriteBase`.

Вот мой файл .htaccess:

```
    AddDefaultCharset utf-8

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

По идее, если я пишу в адресной строке http://mydomen.ru/hello, я должен попасть в папку /controllers/HelloController.php. Но мне приходит 404 страница

```
Not Found


The requested URL /hello was not found on this server.
```

При этом, при запросе на главную http://mydomen.ru/, у меня подключается правильный файл контроллера, исходя из моих маршрутов. То есть все работает.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вы со своим роутером на php разбирайтесь. Все запросы у вас идут на единую точку входа в файл index.php. Дальше должен работать php над ними.

Comment: Попробуй `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: Попробывал, тоже самое